# Atomic floating-point addition

Tags: c++, performance, multithreading, floating-point, atomic

I need to be able to atomically add a 32-bit floating point value to a location in memory. Here is what I came up with. While the code is Windows-specific, I'll extend it with Linux support using `__sync_bool_compare_and_swap()`.

While I tested this code and it appeared to work fine, I'll appreciate a fresh look from another pair of eyes to make sure this code is 100% safe.

I'm also very much interested in any performance advice as this code is used in a hot code path in a performance-sensitive application (interactive rendering).

`atomic_float_add()`, the main function:

```
__forceinline void atomic_float_add(volatile float* ptr, const float operand)
{
    assert(is_aligned(ptr, 4));

    volatile LONG* lptr = reinterpret_cast<volatile LONG*>(ptr);
    LONG lorg, lnew;

    do
    {
        const float forg = *ptr;
        const float fnew = forg + operand;
        lorg = binary_cast<LONG>(forg);
        lnew = binary_cast<LONG>(fnew);
    } while (InterlockedCompareExchange(lptr, lnew, lorg) != lorg);
}
```

`binary_cast()` is implemented in such a way that it obeys strict aliasing rules:

```
template <typename Target, typename Source>
inline Target binary_cast(Source s)
{
    BOOST_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(Target) == sizeof(Source));

    union
    {
        Source  m_source;
        Target  m_target;
    } u;

    u.m_source = s;
    return u.m_target;
}
```

`is_aligned()`:

```
template <typename T>
inline bool is_aligned(const T ptr, const size_t alignment)
{
    assert(alignment > 0);
    assert(is_pow2(alignment));

    const uintptr_t p = (uintptr_t)ptr;
    return (p & (alignment - 1)) == 0;
}
```

`is_pow2()`:

```
template <typename T>
inline bool is_pow2(const T x)
{
    return (x & (x - 1)) == 0;
}
```

Assembly output for `atomic_float_add()` (Visual Studio 2013, full optimization):

```
lorg$ = 8
ptr$ = 8
lnew$ = 16
operand$ = 16
?atomic_float_add@?A0x1534477b@foundation@@YAXPECMM@Z PROC

    prefetchw BYTE PTR [rcx]
    npad    13

$LL3@atomic_flo:
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rcx]
    movss   DWORD PTR lorg$[rsp], xmm0
    addss   xmm0, xmm1
    mov eax, DWORD PTR lorg$[rsp]
    movss   DWORD PTR lnew$[rsp], xmm0
    mov edx, DWORD PTR lnew$[rsp]
    lock cmpxchg DWORD PTR [rcx], edx
    jne SHORT $LL3@atomic_flo

    ret 0

?atomic_float_add@?A0x1534477b@foundation@@YAXPECMM@Z ENDP
```

EDIT: here's a bit of context on how this code is used:

[image: Profile showing that atomic_float_add() is a hot spot]

As you can see, `atomic_float_add()` is taking the bulk of the time of `FilteredTile::add()`, which itself is the most expensive function of the whole program in this particular setup, taking nearly 27% of the overall time.

Comment: Can you not use `std::atomic<>`?

Comment: For various reasons our code base is stuck to C++03 for at least another year, so no `std::atomic`. This is beyond our control. In any case, C++11's and Boost's atomics require a type change which is not acceptable in our context.

Comment: Besides trying SIMD I don't think there would be anything else to optimize. Also, ideally you would try to remove thread contention so that your work units can run in parallel without locking.

Comment: Thanks @glampert. The work unit work in parallel; this is just the place where their results are merged. Since the purpose is interactive rendering, the results need to be merged regularly to provide visual feedback. Regarding SIMD: unfortunately I'm not sure that would help since AFAIK there's no way to SIMD compare-and-exchange primitive. Regarding performance, I was wondering if for instance there were weakers variants of `InterlockedCompareExchange`, something with weaker semantics maybe?

Comment: That all makes sense. Unfortunately I don't know enough about lock-free threading to help you any further.

Comment: Given that `InterlockedCompareExchange` returns the current value, you do not have to load from `ptr` in the loop if you reverse one of the `binary_cast`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@EOF commented that `InterlockedCompareExchange` (and its gcc counterpart, `__sync_val_compare_and_swap`) returns the initial value of the destination address. This allows to remove one memory load from the retry loop.

Here is the new version with this optimization:

```
__forceinline void atomic_float_add(volatile float* ptr, const float operand)
{
    assert(is_aligned(ptr, 4));

    volatile LONG* iptr = reinterpret_cast<volatile LONG*>(ptr);
    LONG expected = *iptr;

    while (true)
    {
        const float value = binary_cast<float>(expected);
        const LONG new_value = binary_cast<LONG>(value + operand);
        const LONG actual = InterlockedCompareExchange(iptr, new_value, expected);
        if (actual == expected)
            return;
        expected = actual;
    }
}
```

Here is the corresponding assembly:

```
?atomic_float_add@foundation@@YAXPECMM@Z PROC

    mov eax, DWORD PTR [rcx]
    mov r8, rcx
    mov DWORD PTR value$2[rsp], eax
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR value$2[rsp]
    addss   xmm0, xmm1
    movss   DWORD PTR new_value$1[rsp], xmm0
    mov edx, DWORD PTR new_value$1[rsp]
    lock cmpxchg DWORD PTR [rcx], edx
    je  SHORT $LN16@atomic_float_add
    npad    13

$LL3@atomic_float_add:
    mov DWORD PTR value$2[rsp], eax
    mov edx, eax
    movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR value$2[rsp]
    addss   xmm0, xmm1
    movss   DWORD PTR new_value$1[rsp], xmm0
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR new_value$1[rsp]
    lock cmpxchg DWORD PTR [r8], ecx
    cmp eax, edx
    jne SHORT $LL3@atomic_float_add

$LN16@atomic_float_add:
    ret 0

?atomic_float_add@foundation@@YAXPECMM@Z ENDP
```

Interestingly, the compiler decided to do one iteration before entering the loop. I'm not sure I understand the benefit of this...

Answer (score 0):

In order to not overlook the obvious, adding heuristics:

```
__forceinline void atomic_float_add(volatile float* ptr, const float operand)
{
    if (operand == 0) {
        return;
    }
    ...
```

and

```
if (weight == 0) {
} else if (weight == 1) {
    memcopy(ptr, values, e * sizeof(float));
    ptr += e;
} else {
    for (size_t i = 0, e = m_channel_count - 1; i < e; ++i)
    {
        *ptr++ += values[i] * weight;
    }
}
```

Where the comparisons might add an epsilon.

It depends on the frequencies of 0.0 and 1.0. Which I am afraid you tested already.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input, appreciated! Unfortunately `operand` is almost never 0 or 1 so there's nothing to gain here...